# metabuilder checked listbox selected index changed not working on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

am using meta builder checked listbox and their selected index changed working fine in local.but not working on server side. please help me to fix this error. My partial code is here..

```
    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        if (ListBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    lblempid.Text = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.Items[i].Text.Substring(0, 8));
                    lblempname.Text = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.Items[i].Text.Substring(9));
                    DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_GetallpayperiodTableAdapter TA = new DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_GetallpayperiodTableAdapter();
                    DataSet5.sp_GetallpayperiodDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
                    if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        fromdate = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[DS.Rows.Count - 1]["fldstartdate"]);
                        todate = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[DS.Rows.Count - 1]["fldtodate"]);
                        status = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[DS.Rows.Count - 1]["fldstatus"]);
                        if (status == "OPEN")
                        {
                            lblfromdate.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate).ToShortDateString());
                            lbltodate.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(todate).ToShortDateString());
                        }
                    } 

                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onload", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + e1.Message + "');</script>", false);
    }
```

Design code:

```
       <%@ Register Assembly="MetaBuilders.WebControls" Namespace="MetaBuilders.WebControls"
TagPrefix="mb" %>

        <mb:CheckedListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="250px"
                                                                            Height="515px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                                        </mb:CheckedListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if the auto post back is true in your aspx code:
Example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlForecastOption" runat="server" 
      onselectedindexchanged="ddlForecastOption_SelectedIndexChanged" 
      AutoPostBack="true">
```